# If $I\subset J\subset R$, with $I,J$ ideals, is there any relationship between their resolutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This question is very general, and certainly doesn't have a general answer, but I'm interested in different settings where meaningful statements can be made.

As a specific example, suppose $R$ is Noetherian and $I=\langle g_1,\dots, g_r\rangle$, and $J=\langle g_1, \dots, g_r, \dots, g_s\rangle$.  If we have a resolution of $J$, is there a way to pass to a resolution of $I$ through some systematic deletion of the generators $g_{r+1},\dots, g_s$?